# Android Pie - No response for JSONObjectRequest in Volley

Tags: android, api, android-volley

I am unable to fetch any response in Volley for Android Pie ? Is there any special configuration required for Android Pie ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question by giving more details of what you have done, what you wish to achieve and what error you get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to your manifest `<application` tag.

and make sure you've got Internet Permission.

Comment: Thank u so much. Issue is resolved. May i know what does it mean and why is it required ?

Comment: That's just an additional protecting layout which introduced in android P and prevents some unsafe connections.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code that below here

Step 1 create xml folder into res folder at android project

Step 2 create one file into xml folder like below:

#

file name : network_security_config.xml

```
    <network-security-config>
     <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
      </trust-anchors>
     </base-config>
  </network-security-config>
```

#

Step 3 in AndroidManifest.xml

```
< application
android:name=".ExampleApplication"
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
android:allowBackup="false"
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```